# Record pyglet screen and convert to numpy array

Tags: python, pyglet

I have created an animation in Pyglet and I want to save this animation as a video retaining the same quality as the Pyglet window. I attempt to use imageio and FFMPEG with Pyglet. See reproducible example below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyglet
import imageio.v2 as iio

window = pyglet.window.Window(480, 480)

label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

    # Capture frame
    color_buffer = pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer()
    image_data = color_buffer.get_image_data()
    buffer = image_data.get_data("RGBA", image_data.pitch)

    # 4 channels: RGBA
    frame = np.frombuffer(buffer).reshape((image_data.height, image_data.width, 4))
    writer.append_data(frame)

writer = iio.get_writer("out.mp4")
pyglet.app.run()
```

Problem:

`buffer` has expected size of `window width * window height * 4`. 
However,  `np.frombuffer(buffer)` has size `buffer size / 8`. I do not know why. I expect the size to be equal. Hence, the program fails at the reshape step.

Comment: `buffer` is undefined. [mre] please.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

Instead of `np.frombuffer(buffer)`, use `np.asarray(buffer)`. Furthermore, the image is not correctly oriented, This can be fixed with `np.flipud`.

```py
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

    # Capture frame
    color_buffer = pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer()
    image_data = color_buffer.get_image_data()
    buffer = image_data.get_data("RGBA", image_data.pitch)

    # 4 channels: RGBA
    frame = np.asarray(buffer).reshape((image_data.height, image_data.width, 4))
    # Make image correctly oriented
    frame = np.flipud(frame)
    writer.append_data(frame)
```